# Getting a list of current APPLICATIONS running, not processes c#

Tags: c#, process

I know you can get a list of the current processes that are running by using `Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();` or `Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("processName");`

However I need to grab the current *applications* that are running, not necessarily the specific processes. The reason is because sometimes there are processes that run in the background that relate to a certain application however the actual application itself is not running. But for my purposes I need to know if the actual application itself is running.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Edit: Apparently I haven't made myself clear. For example in Task Manager you can see a list of Applications that are currently running, as well as a list of Processes that are currently running. I'm trying to grab the list of Applications that one can see in Task Manager, not the extensive list of processes

Comment: How do you even define an application if it's not a process? Please read [ask]

Comment: Edited to hopefully clarify what i mean

Comment: Any specific Windows version? In Windows 10, at least, the list is not always right. For example, right now Chrome is a "background process" when it's obviously an Application (most of the time it appears as an app). I don't think MS publishes how they determine this though

Comment: Interesting how it is Windows version specific-- that actually helps me debug my problem a little, thanks. I'm currently trying to grab from Windows 7. On Windows 10 grabbing just the process works fine, but on Windows 7 it appears for my specific case i need to grab the "Application"

Answer (score 8):

Get the list of processes, then filter by those processes that have a [`MainWindowHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> A process has a main window associated with it only if the process has a graphical interface. If the associated process does not have a main window, the MainWindowHandle value is zero. The value is also zero for processes that have been hidden, that is, processes that are not visible in the taskbar. This can be the case for processes that appear as icons in the notification area, at the far right of the taskbar.

If it has a main window, it's an "application" as far as the Task Manager is concerned.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses()
    .Where(p=> p.MainWindowHandle != 0)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Amy's answer is the one, but I had to change it to

```
var running_apps = Process.GetProcesses()
                          .Where(p => (long)p.MainWindowHandle != 0)
                          .ToArray();
```