# How to get currently running app processes in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process

I understand that using `Process.GetProcesses()` you can get all of the currently running processes but how do I get only the processes that are shown down on the menu:
[image]
or the ones that are shown on the "Apps" part of the Task Manager:
[image]

Also how can I get only the currently opened process? (e.g my Google Chrome is currently opened for me to type this) If I switch to Visual Studio it changed to Visual Studio process... you get the idea.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to get the `Apps` section from TaskManager? I do not think you can get the apps that are attached to the taskbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of current APPLICATIONS running, not processes c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202379/getting-a-list-of-current-applications-running-not-processes-c-sharp)